# Why can't I see the entire POST string in Netbeans HTTP Server Monitor?

Tags: http, servlets, netbeans

I recently started looking at the "HTTP Server Monitor" option in Netbeans (popped up by itself), and it looks to be quite useful. My GUI Client, an application written in Java, communicates to the Tomcat server via the HTTPClient library using HTTP POSTs. However, in the HTTP Server Monitor Request tab, the "Query String" is empty, and a message at the bottom says "Data sent with the request was not parameterized". I would expect to see the complete POST request somewhere.

Is there a way to configure the HTTP Server Monitor to show the full POST request?

FYI, my system is communicating just fine, and I can switch it into a "debug" mode where the full strings are sent to a log file. However, it would be much more convenient if I could see the client/server communication directly in the IDE, if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The term "query string" refers to the 'parameters section' of an url. The doesn't include post parameters. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for more information.

Comment: You are correct in that I misunderstood the purpose of the "Query String" field, but that doesn't really answer my question. My question is really about Netbeans - is there a way to show the full POST request in Netbeans?